# Test for differences in paired data

Tags: regression, t-test, paired-data

I am unsure which statistical test is appropriate for my data. A simple paired t-test seemed correct at first however I no longer think this is the case.

For my data, I want to know if the animals within a population changed burrows between days at a similar frequency before or after a treatment. Records were only included if the animal was located on consecutive days and the animal was considered to have moved if the animal was at different burrows on consecutive days. The same animals were monitored both before and after the treatment however the number of days that the animals were monitored varied both between individuals and before and after.

This seems like it should be simple but I have become quite confused. The paired T-test does not seem correct as this does not take into consideration that there is considerable variation between the observations. Again, realising that the data has a poisson distribution, it seems even less appropriate. I have also considered a generalised linear model using the days observed as an offset but this doesn't seem to take into consideration that the data is paired.

Below is an example of what my data looks like, not the actual data itself:

| Animal | Treatment | Days moved | Days observed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | Pre | 5 | 20 |
| A1 | Post | 8 | 23 |
| A2 | Pre | 2 | 5 |
| A2 | Post | 10 | 19 |
| A3 | Pre | 15 | 17 |
| A3 | Post | 19 | 25 |
| A4 | Pre | 2 | 20 |
| A4 | Post | 1 | 30 |

I apologise if this has been answered elsewhere but I haven't been able to find a relevant example.

Comment: For the four animals taken individually (one at a time), `prop.test` in R finds no significant differences--either because proportions are nearly equal pre and post, or because there are not enough observations for reliable results. Nor (without testing) was there any consistent tendency among the four for more or less movement post.// What pattern of differences did you expect to find? // Ideally, such an expt will have advance planning as to stat analysis and as to numbers of observations likely required in order to find a significant effect (if present). [Power & sample size computation.]

Comment: Thanks for your reply and advice on pre planning and power analysis. The data I included in the table isn't my data but is an example of the format of my data. Sorry if this was not clear. There were 10 animals in the study, which would have had more if things went to plan but that rarely happens when working with threatened species. We were expecting to find a difference after the treatment (more movement) however there doesn't seem to be an obvious pattern in this data. 

I will have a look into prop.test and two proportions z-test. Thanks again.